Error: The operation could not be completed. (Could not make graph API request error -1)
I am trying add Facebook login feature to my swiftUi app. But getting the following error when I download it from testFlight and installed it on a real device.

When I am trying to check it on simulator I get the following error:

Here is the login function:
func loginWithFacebook() {
        let loginManager = LoginManager()
        
        loginManager.logOut()

        loginManager.logIn(permissions: ["public_profile"], from: nil) { result, error in
            if let error = error {
//                showAlert(msg: "Facebook login failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                print("Facebook login failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                // Handle login failure
            } else if result?.isCancelled == true {
//                showAlert(msg: "Facebook login was cancelled")
                print("Facebook login was cancelled")
                // Handle login cancellation
            } else {
                print("Facebook login successful")
                
                guard let token = AccessToken.current else { return }
                
                if token.hasGranted(permission: "public_profile") {
                    // Perform a Graph API request to get user's profile data
                    let graphRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id,name"], tokenString: token.tokenString, version: nil, httpMethod: .get)

                    graphRequest.start { _, result, error in
                        if let error = error {
                            showAlert(msg: "Failed to fetch Facebook user data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            print("Failed to fetch Facebook user data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            // Handle the error
                        } else if let userData = result as? [String: Any] {
                            // Extract user information
                            if let userID = userData["id"] as? String,
                               let userName = userData["name"] as? String {
                                print("User ID: \(userID)")
                                print("User Name: \(userName)")

                                // Perform additional actions with the user data
                                otherLogingType = "facebook"
                                submitOtherLogin(username: userName, userEmail: "", userId: userID)
//                                showAlert(msg: "No issue with Facebook, check other login API")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

I have checked all the documents and nothing really helped.
